# How can I make NaN values sum to NaN rather than 0 when using df.resample?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have the following example dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = {'date': pd.date_range(start='2022-12-09 00:00:00',
                               end='2022-12-09 02:50:00',
                               freq='10min'),
         'amount': [np.nan]*6 + [1]*5 + [np.nan] +[2]*6}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
                  date  amount
0  2022-12-09 00:00:00     NaN
1  2022-12-09 00:10:00     NaN
2  2022-12-09 00:20:00     NaN
3  2022-12-09 00:30:00     NaN
4  2022-12-09 00:40:00     NaN
5  2022-12-09 00:50:00     NaN
6  2022-12-09 01:00:00     1.0
7  2022-12-09 01:10:00     1.0
8  2022-12-09 01:20:00     1.0
9  2022-12-09 01:30:00     1.0
10 2022-12-09 01:40:00     1.0
11 2022-12-09 01:50:00     NaN
12 2022-12-09 02:00:00     2.0
13 2022-12-09 02:10:00     2.0
14 2022-12-09 02:20:00     2.0
15 2022-12-09 02:30:00     2.0
16 2022-12-09 02:40:00     2.0
17 2022-12-09 02:50:00     2.0
```

I am trying to use `df.resample` on this dataframe to aggregate the columns by hour as follows:

```
>>> df.resample(rule='H', on='date').agg({'amount': sum})
                     amount
date                       
2022-12-09 00:00:00     0.0
2022-12-09 01:00:00     5.0
2022-12-09 02:00:00    12.0
```

However, I would like to have hours which contain just `NaN` values to aggregate to `NaN` rather than `0`. Hours which contain a mix of `NaN` and numerical numbers should treat `NaN` as `0` as currently. My desired output is as follows:

```
                     amount
date                       
2022-12-09 00:00:00     NaN
2022-12-09 01:00:00     5.0
2022-12-09 02:00:00    12.0
```

Is there any way to achieve this - ideally using `df.resample` - or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) with `min_count=1` parameter:

```
df = df.resample(rule='H', on='date').agg({'amount': lambda x: x.sum(min_count=1)})
print (df)
                     amount
date                       
2022-12-09 00:00:00     NaN
2022-12-09 01:00:00     5.0
2022-12-09 02:00:00    12.0
```

Or if need processing column(s) by resample with `sum`:

```
s = df.resample(rule='H', on='date')['amount'].sum(min_count=1)
print (s)
date
2022-12-09 00:00:00     NaN
2022-12-09 01:00:00     5.0
2022-12-09 02:00:00    12.0
Freq: H, Name: amount, dtype: float64
```